# Comparing date with current month and write down a status

Tags: excel, vba, date

I have a macro that checks that a date from a column matches the current month. If yes, writes the status "ok", if it does not match, writes "not ok". For example, today is 28.07.2022. All dates from 01.07 onwards will be ok, any date before 01.07 is "not ok". Everything works fine, but now I need to add a condition to compare not only the current month, but -7 days - i.e. according to our example, dates up to 24.06 inclusive were also with the status "ok".

I will appreciate if some one can help me.

```
Sub checkdate()
Dim d1 As Date
Dim WSStart As Worksheet
Dim r, lastrow
Dim sFormatDate As String

Set WSStart = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
lastrow = WSStart.Cells(WSStart.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row


d1 = DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date), 1)
sFormatDate = Format(d1, "YYYYMM")

For r = 2 To lastrow

dd = WSStart.Cells(r, 7).Value

      If Format(dd, "YYYYMM") <> sFormatDate Then
      WSStart.Cells(r, 11).Value = "not ok"
   Else
      WSStart.Cells(r, 11).Value = "ok"
   End If
 
  Next

 End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use *DateDiff* and *DateAdd* and avoid string handling of dates:

```vb
d1 = DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date), 1)

If DateDiff("m", Date, DateAdd("d", 6, dd)) <> 0 Then
    WSStart.Cells(r, 11).Value = "not ok"
Else
    WSStart.Cells(r, 11).Value = "ok"
End If
```

If dd is *text*, then convert to true DateTime:

```vb
If DateDiff("m", Date, DateAdd("d", 6, CDate(Format(dd, "@@@@\/@@")))) <> 0 Then
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply!
I pasted it to my code and all dates became "not ok". also dates of July are "not ok" too..

Comment: Then, I guess, your dd is not a date but _text_. See extended answer, please.

Comment: Thank you! It works perfect! I will post the next comment in this threat to show the full macro. May be someone will get it ;)

Comment: Gustav, one more question - sometimes it can be not a date but a text.  My first macro wrote "not ok" and didn't crash, but now if there is something not a date it crashes. I changed "IF DateDiff" construction to  your additional comment, but it has a mistake "Type mismath". Is there no mistake in "@@@@\/@@" ?

Comment: No there isn't. But, of course, the cell values must conform to the format. You can check with: `If IsDate(Format(dd, "@@@@\/@@")) Then ' ...  dd is yyyymm`.

Comment: Gustav, yes. If I put 
   `If IsDate(Format(dd, "@@@@\/@@")) Then`     - its ok

But if I add the line:
    `If DateDiff("m", Date, DateAdd("d", 6, CDate((Format(dd, "@@@@\/@@"))))) <> 0 Then` - it has type mismatch. 

I suppose I need to add this line cause sometimes it may be something like that - "fnnsfnjs"

Comment: Oh... and I found one more issue - I write down dates beginig from 24.07.2022 till 03.08.
24.06 - not ok
25.06  - 25.07 - ok
26.07 - 01.08 - not ok
but all from 25.06 - 31.07 - should be ok

Comment: There is no easy or universal solution to read and convert mixed formats of dates. Either correct manually to a consistent format, or write extensive code that will use _trial-and-error_ for a list of formats until success. One attempt is the function `ParseDate` found in module `DateText.bas` in my libary at GitHub: [VBA.Date](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.Date).

Answer (score 1):

The new macro, thanks to Gustav :)

```
Sub checkdate()
Dim d1 As Date
Dim WSStart As Worksheet
Dim r, lastrow
Dim sFormatDate As String

Set WSStart = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
lastrow = WSStart.Cells(WSStart.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row


d1 = DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date), 1)


For r = 2 To lastrow
d1 = DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date), 1)
dd = WSStart.Cells(r, 7).Value
If DateDiff("m", Date, DateAdd("d", 6, dd)) <> 0 Then
WSStart.Cells(r, 11).Value = "not ok"
Else
WSStart.Cells(r, 11).Value = "ok"

End If
Next


End Sub
```